# 2D Slider/Trackpad in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, slider

I am trying to figure out a solution to create a 2D slider for x- and y-axis (think computer trackpad) so that I can change different values depending on whether the user drags horizontally or vertically.

I appreciate any help/ideas I can get.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.gesture(DragGesture().onChanged())` for that

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Test")
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        print("x: \(value.location.x)")
                        print("y: \(value.location.y)")
                    })
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Update:**
Ask in comment: "I would like them within the ranges 0.01 to 1.0, is there any chance you know how to solve this?"

**Solution:**
e.g. (value.location.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Test")
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        print("x: \(value.location.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.width)")
                        print("y: \(value.location.y / UIScreen.main.bounds.height)")
                    })
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Decimal limited version**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Test")
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        let valueX = String(format: "%.2f", value.location.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                        let valueY = String(format: "%.2f", value.location.y / UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                        print("x: \(valueX)")
                        print("y: \(valueY)")
                        
                    })
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I'm going to mark your answer as the solution. the next issue I'm facing is to get normalised coordinates for this. I would like them within the ranges 0.01 to 1.0, is there any chance you know how to solve this?

Comment: @justaplaceholdername I updated my post for your ask! Thanks for checking my answer :D